# Why cakephp FormHelper::input() doesn't create a multiple select input on a hasMany association?

Tags: has-many, cakephp-2.4, formhelper

I have a model for which exists some model associations whose hasmay and HABTM.

In the edit view,

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('myHABTMModel'); ?>
```

create a select>multiple input, but

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('myHasManyModel'); ?>
```

create a select input with unique choice.

Why ? It is normal ?
I must specify ?
Or something is wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it must specify the multiplicity in the input method options :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('myHasManyModel',array('multiple'=>'multiple')); ?>
```